# Google Places API Inconsistent Results

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm using Google Places API Nearby Search to find location of places in Berlin for an app I'm building. For a while it was working fine, but now it seems to be playing up and I'm not sure why. It worked a couple of months ago and I stored the place ids in a db. These place ids are no longer valid and I can't get any results for my queries. Example:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=52.525758,13.404029&radius=5000&keyword=Generator%20Hostel%20Berlin%20Mitte&key=(mykey)

Two months ago this returned the place_id = ChIJ8896Z-hRqEcRFBs8c9xKXjc

But using details search on that id I now get:

{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "status" : "NOT_FOUND"
}

If I run my nearby search today I get a couple of results back, none of which are Generator Hostel. If I use the same search on Google Maps App it returns just fine. Other examples of places not working:
THE MANDALA HOTEL, 
La Soupe Populaire.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I don't know if I should call it bug, but currently the places-API may be marked as unusable when you request results from germany, see: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7498 . The only thing you can do is: wait

Comment: This could be a bug, because in the Google Places API documentation, it says `Once moderated and added into the Google database, a place can no longer be deleted`. So if a place data get removed, it could be a bug.

Comment: @ztan: these places haven't been deleted, they are not accessible via the API. On maps.google.com you still may see these places.

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Molle, I'll be patient and wait. It does appear though that some places have been deleted. I have quite a few pace_id's that were valid and working two months ago that aren't working anymore. Many thanks